# Asus Prime Z370-p reboots to bios after windows install

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, uefi

I'm trying to help a friend get his new gaming pc up and going. He bought it from a company called DigitialStorm, and once he received it, wanted to install a fresh copy of windows. However this became an issue. After trying to reinstall several times on his own, he came to me for help.

Looking at the UEFI settings (on a discord video call lol), DigitalStorm seems to have installed windows 10 in legacy mode. I had him turn CSM off and Secure boot on, then reinstall windows. the installation seemed to go well, however once the windows installer got to the first reboot prompt, it rebooted to the usb drive. So he removed it, thinking it was the boot priority, and now it just repeatedly boots to the UEFI, and it wont recognize the SSD as a boot device (despite being the only drive plugged in).

We have tried CSM on/off, Secure Boot on/off, Fast boot On/off, even downloaded a fresh copy of windows 10, wrote it to a USB with rufus (in GPT/UEFI mode) and still the same problem.

I'm now out of ideas. I've never seen a motherboard or windows act this way. Any suggestions?

His new specs:

```
Motherboard: Asus Prime Z370-P
CPU: Core i7-8700k
RAM: 8GB DDR4-3000
SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 250GB
GPU: GTX 1050
```

Comment: You seem to be missing drivers. You don't by any chance have a drivers CD from DigitialStorm, have available drivers on the DigitialStorm website, or saved the working drivers before installing? You will need to slipstream the drivers to the boot. The simplest solution is maybe to ask DigitialStorm for an installation DVD/USB.

Comment: The issue there is, they supplied a USB drive, with a Windows installer on it, and this suffered the same fate as the generic iso from microsoft

Comment: Have you checked boot order? I really don't understand the rush to reinstall Windows on a new computer. Sometimes the generic install does not work and the boot USB lamentably just contains the generic install. Try to slipstream drivers, if you can find them, and if it doesn't succeed replace the computer as being defective (and don't reinstall Windows again).